Нет выбора Manjaro в uefi, dualboot
Поставил на ноут windows 10, потом manjaro.
В настройках boot type priority нет возможности выбрать manjaro. Зато есть две винды.
Однако можно загрузиться в манджару по клавише f12. Также uefi на последней вкладке тоже видит ее. Но выбор boot override ни к чему не приводит, грузится винда.
Поставил refind - таже проблема.
Secure boot, fast boot отключены в настройках.
Сломал весь мозг, плиз хэлп




Загрузитесь в manjaro.
Обновите пакеты.
Или обновите grub принудительно (правильная команда есть на сайте Arch linux-а)


все сделал, не помогло. Я так понял не только в грабе проблема. refind тоже не видно в uefi

1-войти в Биос, найти "security Boot"-отключить(disabled).сохранить настройки, перезагрузка-должен появиться grub или refind. Если ничего не изменилось- приводим ноут в состояние "до" установки манджаро. Читаем документацию на сайте ArchLinux. И не бросаем исследований.Потом ещё и Арч захотите...
